# How to solve problems with scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    height: 30vh;
    margin: 24px;
    background: rgb(194,194,194);
}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgb(245, 134, 134);
}

.content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgb(11, 134, 134);
}

.content-inner {
    display: flex;
}

.content-inner > p {
    flex: 0 0 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <header>Sidebar</header>
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a weird situation, but I hope, it is actual, in general.

As you could notice, the whole wrapper scrolls vertically.
The expected behavior is that I want the `content` section to be scrolled horizontally without affecting sidebar (means that `sidebar` should be always visible and static while scrolling horizontally) and at the same time, the whole content should scrollable vertically as it is now.
I can only achieve the first case, but in that case, when the whole content is being scrolled vertically, `content` sections vertical scrollbar causes it's content to be cut vertically.

> Note that the horizontal scrollbar should be visible on the viewport, and not be at the bottom of the whole content, as the content can be much longer

I want to achieve this via `CSS`. I can do this with JavaScript I assume, but better to be done by CSS.

Comment: See attached codepen

Comment: Here it is , Done !

Comment: [It looks like](https://jsfiddle.net/c05k12es/) setting `.wrapper {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}` and `.content {overflow-x: auto; overflow-y:hidden;}` would do the trick.

Comment: In that case, the content gets cut vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I made these two changes to make it work -

1. Adding `align-items: flex-start` to `.wrapper`, this solves the issue of containers getting cut.
2. Adding `overflow-x: auto` to `.content`, to enable horizontal scrolling.

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    height: 40vh;
    margin: 24px;
    background: rgb(194,194,194);
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 150px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgb(245, 134, 134);
}

.content {
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgb(11, 134, 134);
}

.content-inner {
    display: flex;
}

.content-inner > p {
    flex: 0 0 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Great Demo on CodePen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <header>Sidebar</header>
            <div class="sidebar-content">
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
                <p>Sidebar content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually yes, but the scrollbar should be visible on the viewport, not at the bottom of the content, as the content can be very long. I updated the question regarding this `NOTE`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```css
.scroll-area {
 width:85%;
    float:left;
  overflow: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
}
.sidebar
{
    width:15%;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h1 class="logo">Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="rightcontent">
  <div class="scroll-area">
    <div class="image-gallery">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x800"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The scrollbar should be visible on the viewport, not at the bottom of the content, as the content can be very long.